# Lyx won't create PDF - "File doesn't exist"

Tags: lyx, pdf

I'm new using Lyx, and apparently I don't understand it very well. My problem is when I try to compile a file to pdf.

When I click "View", the debug messages shows the following:

```
08:46:53.880: Previewing ... 
08:46:53.901: (buffer-view: Ctrl+R) 
08:46:54.064: pdflatex  "New.tex" 
08:46:54.373: This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (MiKTeX 2.9)
08:46:54.376: entering extended mode 08:46:54.377: ! I can't find file `New.tex'.
08:46:54.379: <*> New.tex 08:46:54.380:
```

and then it loads for a minute or two, until a message box pops up, which says:

```
"The command pdflatex "New.tex" has not completed. Do you want to stop
it?"
```

If I click "Let it Run", it just continues... very slowly... But with no success in the end. If I click Stop, I get the message:

```
"File does not exist:
C:\Users\JohanEmil\AppData\Local\Temp\lyx_tmpdir.FIEYeMyf6432/lyx_tmpbuff0/New.pdf"
```

I have googled this problem, and it seems that others have had the same. I see that a lot of people suggest that one should run stuff like

```
fmtutil --all
updmap --enable Map=txfonts.map
sudo texhash
```

I don't know how to run this? I somehow sense that it might be from Lyx Preferences --> File Handling --> Converters --> LaTeX (pdflatex) -> PDF (pdflatex)?
(If Im wrong, please correct me!)

At the moment, it just says `pdflatex $$i` in the "Converter" and `latex=pdflatex` in the "Extra Flag".

I'm really confused... Hope someone can help. I would be extremely grateful :)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Just a quick thought: The log says pdfTeX couldn't find the file 'New.tex' (``08:46:54.376: entering extended mode 08:46:54.377: ! I can't find file `New.tex'.``). So I wonder, have you saved the source file before trying to compile it? Have you manually checked whether the file is present or not (in Windows explorer... I suppose you are on Windows, considering some indicators from your post)?

Comment: I have saved the source file, New.tex, in the folder, yes. I just tried to delete it and save it again. Now I was able to do a File-->Export--> PDF (pdflatex)

The strange this is though, that I still can't use the "view function" - it still says that the file does not exist. 

Furthermore, if I change something in the document now, and export to PDF again using the method above, it doesn't generate a new pdf, but just keep the old one! 
If I delete the pdf and generate a new one, my changes in the document are not saved, but it just generates the same as before.

Comment: [Bug-report #7924](http://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/7924) from the LyX bug tracker, looks quite similar.

Unfortunately it's been reported 3 years ago, the last activity has been 2 years ago and no real advances/solutions have been reported so far.

Try if you can compile the LyX-project file (*.lyx) with LyX from the command line (as mentioned in the bug-report's 6th comment). Then add a comment with your findings together with your platform and LyX version to that bug report (to get activity back to that topic)... but on short term I'm afraid there might be nothing you can do about it now.

Comment: @PierreSchroeder Are you by chance using Adobe Acrobat as your PDF viewer? We've seen people have success by using Sumatra.

Comment: Maybe that question should be directed to and answered by the author of the question. (I'm not using LyX at all!)

Comment: @PierreSchroeder good point :)

Comment: @JohanEmilRasmussen Are you by chance using Adobe Acrobat as your PDF viewer? We've seen people have success by using Sumatra

Comment: I was using adobe acrobat. It might have been the problem, but I don't know for sure. 
My pc was behaving quite strange, so I did a format... Now it works :)

Thanks for all your help though. 

/Johan

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a local problem solved by formatting the computer.